# Table like indexed collection filtering

Tags: java, collections

I need a simple database like structure for indexed searching. It will be used in an applet so I don't want to use an additional embedded database jar.

To Sum Up:
I try to explain with an anology. For instance a students table:

```
Students
------------------
Score
Gender
Name
```

I want to filter `SCORE > 40 AND SCORE < 80 AND GENDER = MALE`
Solutions that I found make full table scan. But I am searching a solution like TreeMap.

I made a simple solution like partitioning using TreeMap's.

```
package multikey;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.SortedMap;
import java.util.TreeMap;


public class MultiKey {




    public MultiKey() {

        final Integer MALE   = 1;
        final Integer FEMALE = 2;

        List<Student>                                    students = new ArrayList<Student>();
        TreeMap<Integer, TreeMap<Integer, List<String>>> table;

        students.add(new Student(80, MALE, "John"));
        students.add(new Student(80, FEMALE, "Monica"));
        students.add(new Student(70, MALE, "Michael"));
        students.add(new Student(60, MALE, "Brad"));
        students.add(new Student(60, FEMALE, "Angelina"));
        students.add(new Student(50, MALE, "Steve"));
        students.add(new Student(40, MALE, "Alex"));

        table = new TreeMap<Integer, TreeMap<Integer, List<String>>>();

        for (Student student : students) {
            Integer                        score     = student.score;
            Integer                        gender    = student.gender;
            TreeMap<Integer, List<String>> genderMap;
            List<String>                   names;

            if ((genderMap = table.get(score)) == null) {
                genderMap = new TreeMap<Integer, List<String>>();
                table.put(score, genderMap);
            }

            if ((names = genderMap.get(gender)) == null) {
                names = new ArrayList<String>();
                genderMap.put(gender, names);
            }

            names.add(student.name);
        }

        // 50 - 70 arasında alan erkekler
        SortedMap<Integer, TreeMap<Integer, List<String>>> students5070 = table.subMap(50, 71);
        List<String>                                       filtered     = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (Integer score : students5070.keySet()) {
            filtered.addAll(students5070.get(score).get(MALE));
        }

        System.out.println(filtered);
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new MultiKey();
    }




    public class Student {




        private int    gender;
        private String name;
        private int    score;




        public Student(int score, int gender, String name) {

            this.score  = score;
            this.gender = gender;
            this.name   = name;
        }




        public int getGender() {

            return gender;
        }



        public String getName() {

            return name;
        }




        public int getScore() {

            return score;
        }




        @Override
        public String toString() {

            return name;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How many records do you have?

Comment: you can just filter them by linear scan each time. 10,000 is an extremely small list. Will probably be faster than any other solution if you have even 10x the number of records. Say you have 10^5 records, each record takes, say, 1000 instructions (high estimate) to determine if it matches, a 1ghz processor is going to do this in about 0.1 seconds. Should be quick enough right?

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is a table, [guava tables](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Table.html) might help you, if only as a reference. If you need more SQL like syntax... I don't think you can avoid using something like a pure hava SQL database like [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/)